# Set SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory to networked file location

Tags: savefiledialog, filedialog

I'm using the Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog class. When I set the InitialDirectory to a networked location 
(E.g. "\localhost\Share\") it opens up to the Documents folder instead of the networked file location. I've set permissions to allow Everyone read/write to this directory.

Test code let dir = "\localhost\Share\"

```
var dlg = new SaveFileDialog { InitialDirectory = dir };
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    fileName = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Is this a limitation of the class, or could it be file permission issues?